# Radio Button Validation

Tags: devexpress

Hii.

In my project, in the main page, I've a ASPxPageControl and ASPxPopupControl. In the ASPxPopUpControl, I've a form consits of two radio buttons and so many text fields and combo boxes etc. In the ASPxPageControl, there are two tabs.

The PopUpElement of ASPxPopupControl is in the second tab. And on the PageLoad(), I've configured to display the first tab.

I want to enable/disable texbox in the form according to the user selection of the radio button. But, when AutoPostBack is enabled, the entire page is refreshed, and the default tab will be the first one. And to resume the form, i've to manually click the second tab and the ASPxPopupControl will open automatically.

Is there anyway to resolve this?? Is there any other control other than radio button to do this?(Which accepts client side scripting)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, Do you need to postback to enable/disable textboxes? you have rich ClientSide Events for Textboxes to enable/disable/hide them (`SetVisible, SetEnabled`).

Secondly, you can have your second Tab Content in an AspxCallbackPanel, and when Radio Button changes, you Can do a CallbackPanel Refresh (`PerformCallback`). Thus, only the Tab Content will update.